# setting suse sless12.5 keyboard short cuts - after getting to 'walk through windows' bar, how to go in both direction with arrows(like in windows)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, suse

I'm running *Suse sles 12.5* (through a remote machine with VNC) and I set the  **'walk through windows'** shortcut to be 'ctrl+tab' because 'alt+tab' is used by windows. In windows, when you get to that 'walk through' bar, with the left/right arrows you can move back and forth. I can't find this capability/shortcut in 'global shortcuts' inside 'system settings'.'shortcuts'

Is it possible?